why flutter app stuck on web on fist page?
I have a simple flutter app it's working well and fast on android .
Also it's working well on web build mode.
But in web release mode it's stuck in first page.
I checked the console logs in inspect it's repeat the below error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')
at main.dart.js:43310:3
at b_c.a (main.dart.js:6954:63)
at b_c.$2 (main.dart.js:51742:14)
at Object.t (main.dart.js:6940:10)
at avs.aGr (main.dart.js:43316:10)
at avs.rp (main.dart.js:43305:21)
at main.dart.js:44976:19
at b_c.a (main.dart.js:6954:63)
at b_c.$2 (main.dart.js:51742:14)
at Object.t (main.dart.js:6940:10)

Site address is this  pieceshot game
Also it's working better (sometimes loaded in web on desktop) but in mobile is very bad.

It cannot write as string because the value is NULL. Can you add this code to the error value for this?
reading = reading==null ? ' ' : reading.toString();
